# O que é um lock e quais as suas causas?

Tags: sql, terminologia, lock

Frequentemente me deparo com o termo: A tabela x está com `lock`. O que ele significa e quais as suas causas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O SGDB se reguarda ao direito de manipular as tabelas/registros conforme a fila de operações, ou seja, ele realiza bloqueios para garantir a realização das operações pendentes (não *comitadas*).

Locks row e lock table:

- **Row Locks**
  Impede qualquer operação no registro até que outra operação (update por exemplo) seja concluído.
  O SGDB não permitirá uma leitura nesta(s) linha(s) para não exibir dados desatualizados.
- **Table Locks**
  Impede que qualquer alteração, inclusive uma consulta simples de ser efetuada na tabela. Alguma operação não *comitada* está ainda em processo por outra sessão (ou até na mesma - *separadas por GO*)

Diversas situações de congelamento nos sistemas ocorrem por causa destes *locks*;

É possível forçar uma consulta a ignorar este flag:

```
select * from teste with (nolock)
```

Answer (score 2):

Em um banco de dados, quando executamos alguma operação DML (update, insert, delete) nós estamos lockando, ou seja, estamos bloqueando determinado objeto. Isso impede que outra operação realize uma alteração na tabela ou registro ("linha") que estamos a manipular.

O lock é algo natural, ele existe e normalmente não o notamos em operações normais. Porém, quando operações conflitantes, grandes ou não finalizadas são executadas, ai podemos ter muitos objetos locados. Para simplificar vamos imaginar o seguinte cenário:

> Zezinho fez um update na tabela de users, porém, não fez commit (instrução que indica fim da transação), ou seja, ele bloqueou um ou mais registros, se determinada aplicação tentar manipular estes registros lockados, ficara aguardando resposta, o que pode resultar em um travamento desta aplicação.

É valido citar que existe lock de registro e tabela.

O cenário acima é grosseiro, porém, acredito que superficialmente sirva para simplificar o entendimento.

Acredito que o artigo a seguir seja esclarecedor quanto ao assunto: http://www.devmedia.com.br/oracle-locks-parte-i/313